# Convert logical type to double in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

I'm looking for a bulletproof way of converting logical type variables to real type that will work in both ifort and gfortran. The following works in ifort, but *not* in gfortran:

```
logical :: a
real :: b
a = .true.
b = dble(a)
```

The error thrown in gfortran is

```
b = dble(a)
         1
Error: 'a' argument of 'dble' intrinsic at (1) must be a numeric type
```

Obviously, .true. should map to 1.d0, and .false. to 0.d0. What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: For what its worth, if you turn on standard checking ifort should complain.  The reason it works is that processor has an extension that allows implicit conversion of logical to integer, the standard then provides for conversion from integer to real.  Note that when you say "obviously" the internal representation of .TRUE. will look absolutely nothing like a real value of 1.0, while on *some* processors the internal representation of .TRUE. is exactly the same as an integer value of 1 (particularly if default logical and LOGICAL(C_BOOL) are the same representation).

Comment: .true. = -1 is also common (all bits in an integer set to 1, which in 2's complement = -1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure if there is an intrinsic tool that does this. I do not know why ifort accepts this, and my guess would be that it is a compiler specific functionality.

Edit: As pointed out in https://stackoverflow.com/a/15057846/1624033 below, there is the intrinsic **merge** function which is exactly what is needed here.

an option to to this, specifically since you want this to be bullet proof, is to create your own function.

I have not tested this, but the following might work:

```
elemental pure double precision function logic2dbl(a)
  logical, intent(in) :: a

  if (a) then
    logic2dbl = 1.d0
  else
    logic2dbl = 0.d0
  end if
end function logic2dbl
```

Edit: I added **elemental** to the function declaration based on advice below. I also added **pure** to this function as it adds the extra ability to use this in parallel situations and it is good documentation. This however is just my opinion and it is not necessary.

Comment: You should return the value as the function name: `logic2dbl = ...`.

Comment: Also, you should replace the .eq. with .eqv. I'll accept when the answer is syntactically correct!

Comment: Bonus points if you add `elemental` to the function signature so that this function can be used on arrays as well!

Comment: @jvriesem Added that. Great catch!

Answer (score 12):

In addition to writing a function to handle this, you could also directly use the intrinsic merge function: `b = merge(1.d0, 0.d0, a)`. Or you could write a defined assignment subroutine that does this, so that you can just type `b = a`.

Answer (score 0):

In gfortran, I am using the TRANSFER intrinsic for that type of job. 
Assuming a integer variable my_int then:

```
    my_int = transfer(.false.,my_int)
```

the result of my_int is 0 as expected.

Comment: `realvar = transfer( logical  ,  1 ) `  (just put a literal integer 1 for mold ) works (or seems to). Not sure how portable this is though given @WaywiserTundish comment

Answer (score 0):

Just a note, TRANSFER(.true.,1) correctly returns the value of 1 with Gfortran and (incorrectly?) values of -1 with the current versions of Intel and Portland compilers. Interestingly, TRANSFER(-1,logical) returns TRUE with the latter two compilers while throws a syntax error with Gfortran.

Comment: What do you mean by 'correctly returns the value of 1'?  Why is 1 the correct value and -1 an incorrect value?

Comment: Try using your Intel compiler with `-standard-semantics` although there is nothing against the standard with -1 either.

Comment: Anyway, we have a whole question with answers about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39454349/numerical-equivalent-of-true-is-1 I do not think your answer actually answers the question asked here.

Comment: I should probably phrase it as "incorrect" with GNU Fortran result serving as a reference. From Steve Lionel's answer (thanks for a pointer) I understand the logic followed by Intel, but since Portland displays the same behavior and using compilation flags seems less transparent I simply iterate to find the number of true entries in our logical vectors.