# Numerical equivalent of TRUE is -1?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, fortran, logical-operators, intel-fortran

I am using Intel Fortran in Visual Studio 2012 to compile a Fortran code. 
When I try to use logical operators I have noticed that a standalone logical expression results in T or F as expected. However, if I need the numerical T or F (0 or 1), I get a -1 when logical result is T.

For example:

```
integer*4 a
a = 1
logicval = (node(5,L).gt.0)
numval =  1*(node(5,L).gt.0)
write(*,*) logicval, numval
```

would output

> T, -1

Is there a way in which I can redefine numerical values assigned to T & F?

Comment: Note that there is no Visual Studio Fortran. There are several vendors of Fortran compilers, but the most common is Intel.

Comment: @VladimirF  I am using Intel FORTRAN and using Visual Studio as an IDE. I should edit to make it clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is expected Intel Fortran's TRUE is indeed -1, because all bits are set to 1.

In addition, your use of integers as logical (Boolean) variables is completely non-standard. You should make your code a few lines longer and always do proper conversion. Your `integer_var = 1*(node(5,L).gt.0)` is not allowed in Fortran and it **will be refused** by many compilers. If you drop the `1*` gfortran will issue a warning, but your form results in an error.

---

You can simply convert your logicals and integers in a standard conforming way

```
   if (l) then
     x = 1
   else
     x = 0
   end if
```

You can convert a Fortran logical arrays to integer arrays with 1 and 0 easily using the `MERGE()` intrisic or using `WHERE`.

---

An easy fix for Intel Fortran is probably `-fpscomp logicals` for Intel Fortran which switches the treatment of `LOGICAL` type to consider anything nonzero as true and makes the `.true.` constant to be equivalent to integer 1.

Still be careful because it does not make your program portable, it just works around one portability issue in one particular compiler.

---

You can use the C interoperable logical kind to match the definition to the Intel C representation:

```
use iso_c_binding

logical(c_bool) :: variable
```

These will have values of +1 and 0 as C99 dictates for _Bool. If you need them to be interoperable with `int` you must do some simple conversion. `C_int` is not compatible with `c_bool`.

Depending on the version of Intel Compiler you may need to use `-standard-semantics` (or `-fpscomp logicals`) for correct `logical(c_bool)`. I consider this to be *very* unfortunate.

Comment: This is quite comprehensive and quite useful for me.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately, this is another case where a new standard specified behavior that conflicted with long existing practice. Intel Fortran is derived from DEC Fortran, which adopted the even/odd practice for LOGICAL back in the 1970s, which was very useful for tests on VAX hardware (it had a branch-on-low-bit clear/set instruction pair) and for interpreting VMS condition values. It wasn't until Fortran 2003 that the standard said anything about the representation of LOGICAL types, and then only obliquely. What I consider unfortunate was the inclusion of LOGICAL as an interoperable type.

Comment: @SteveLionel I just thought that the interoperable kind could have different representation from the default kind and no flag would be necessary.

Comment: @VladimirF, I suppose that would be possible but it's a VERY complicated and costly thing to implement for limited benefit. Since Intel Fortran has other defaults that are different from the standard, -standard-semantics takes care of all of them.

Answer (score 5):

As others have stated, the Intel Fortran default for this non-standard usage is that integer values with the low bit set (odd) are true, even values (low bit clear) are false. The constant .TRUE. has the bit pattern of -1. It gets more complicated when you do conversions and up until version 17 the compiler hasn't been completely consistent in this. Note that if you use -standard-semantics, -fpscomp logicals is implied.

Please read https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/275071#comment-1548435 and also the version 17 release notes (https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-fortran-compiler-170-release-notes) for information on the changes in that version for how numeric-logical conversions are handled.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your linked post was very helpful.
And just BTW, your answers/posts on Intel website are quite helpful and have helped me immensely on multiple occasions.